# GLSL color with texture ontop

Tags: colors, textures, glsl

Is it possible to get GLSL to produce this:
[image]

This is my fragment shader:

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D diffuse;

varying vec3 shared_colors;
varying vec2 shared_texCoords;

void main() {
    vec4 color = vec4(shared_colors, 1);
    vec4 texture = texture2D(diffuse, shared_texCoords);
    vec4 finalColor = vec4(mix(color.rgb, texture.rgb, texture.a), 1);
    vec4 fCol = color * texture;

    gl_FragColor = fCol;
}
```

My results are:

- finalColor = red color, no texture
- fCol = no color (black), red texture

I want to set the color of the object and have that show through wherever the alpha of the texture is less than 1...

Comment: Found my problem. It was not actally in the shader file! It was my SDL_CreateRGBSurface() missing the parameters for RGBA masks.
I solved it by passing: 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff, 0xff000000

Comment: Can you update the question (or maybe better yet, write a brief answer) showing some of the background code where the error occurred? It would be very helpful for others running into similar problems!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my texture was not loaded correctly after all, as it gave me a constant alpha value of 0, so when I tried to call the Mix() in the GLSL it ended up canceling it completly out.

I loaded the texture like this:

```
SDL_CreateRGBSurface(NULL, rawImage->w, rawImage->h, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

It was solved by setting it to this, so it actually conciders the alpha channel correctly:

```
SDL_CreateRGBSurface(NULL, rawImage->w, rawImage->h, 32, 0x00ff0000, 0x0000ff00, 0x000000ff, 0xff000000);
```

Also after that I found out my texture was loaded with reversed rgb channels (meaning it used bgr), so I also changed that when merging the texture in the shader.
From:

```
vec4 finalColor = vec4(mix(color.rgb, texture.rgb, texture.a), 1);
```

To:

```
vec4 finalColor = vec4(mix(color.rgb, texture.bgr, texture.a), 1);
```